# Problem installing Fedora 23 in VM using KVM on Linux Mint 17.2

Tags: fedora, linux-mint, kvm, virt-manager

I'm unable to install `Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-23-10.iso` into a QEMU2 VM using virt-manager on Linux Mint 17.2. I've verified that the SHA256 checksum on the ISO is correct, and I can install a Debian ISO that is in the same folder without any difficulty. The error I am getting is:

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/fedora23.org.qemu.guest_agent.0,server,nowait: Failed to bind socket: No such file or directory
qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/fedora23.org.qemu.guest_agent.0,server,nowait: chardev: opening backend "socket" failed
'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1873, in do_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 414, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 478, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3202, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/fedora23.org.qemu.guest_agent.0,server,nowait: Failed to bind socket: No such file or directory
qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/fedora23.org.qemu.guest_agent.0,server,nowait: chardev: opening backend "socket" failed
```

Can someone point me in the right direction so I can get this installed? I'll be happy to provide any additional info needed. Thanks.

Comment: Is libvirtd started on the host machine?

Comment: Also, are all qemu components installed properly?

Comment: virt-manager is not complaining that libvirtd is not found, and I can install the Debian ISO, so I believe it is. Same goes for qemu components. I've been using two other VMs regularly for months.

Comment: Do you have updated `libvirt` and stuff? Restarted?

Comment: libvirt and virt-manager are the newest versions available in the Linux Mint repositories, and yes, I have restarted. Twice, actually.

Comment: I realized this should have been asked on Server Fault, so I repeated the question there and found a solution. See http://serverfault.com/questions/760326/unable-to-install-fedora-23-in-vm-using-kvm-on-linux-mint-17-2